# Spring boot web app load new web pages created by another application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a webapp that runs with Spring Boot.
It exposes a REST API and some static web pages with AngularJS.
My problem is that I have another application that creates dynamically some other static web pages in the same location of the first web pages but with subfolders.
It works well but when I want to access them throught my browser, the pages aren't displayed...
To illustrate, here is the structure at the begining:

- webapp

  - index.html

And then:

- webapp

  - index.html
  - directory

    - directory2

      - myPage.html

How to do tell Tomcat It has to refresh its structure?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very strange project structure. you have several possibilities, the first one of them is to store generated pages not in tomcat `webapp` but outside of tomcat, somewhere in the filesystem where tomcat has access.

Other variant is to store all needed resources in database.

The last is to use [tomcat hot relaod](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-reload#manager).

Comment: I want the generated pages in tomcat webapp because there is an basic authentication and I want to avoid to reloging again when I go on the new pages...